# Why do my passengers thread behave the way they do?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I'm writing a multithread program in C using pthreads.
I have 4 bus stops threads. At the start of the program 10 passengers(every one is a different thread) come to bus stops(random ones). They also decide at which stop they want to get out. There is also a bus thread. Bus is driving through the stops. At every stop bus picks up passengers from that stop. Passengers should also exit the bus at bus stop of their destination.

After bus gets to bus stop, it informs bus stop that it arrived. Bus stop checks if there are passengers waiting for the bus. If there are - bus stop informs passengers that they can begin boarding the bus.
To that point - things work fine.

Passengers need to get out of the bus. I have problems with that. They often refuse to exit it.
Im still not killing exited threads and the bus is not being checked for how many people are in there. Work is in progress I guess. I want to work out why passengers behave the way they do.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PASSENGER_NUMBER 10
#define BUS_SEATS 20
#define BUS_STOPS 4

pthread_mutex_t bus;
pthread_mutex_t busStation;

pthread_cond_t signal_1 = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER; // signal for busStation to know that bus came to station
pthread_cond_t signal_2 = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER; // signal for bus to know that it can depart from the station
pthread_cond_t signal_3 = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER; // singal for passengers to know they are free to board the bus

int bus_passenger_number = 0;
int busStopCounter[BUS_STOPS] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
int passengersToGetOut[BUS_STOPS] = {0};
int currentStop = 1;
int loop = 0;
int nextStop = 2;

void *busStopp(void *args) {
    int id = (intptr_t) args;
    while (1) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&signal_1, &bus);
        if (id == currentStop) {
            //printf("PASSENGERS TO GET OUT %d, id = %d\n", passengersToGetOut[id-1], id);
            if (busStopCounter[id - 1] == 0 && passengersToGetOut[id-1] <= 0) { // no people at stop
                pthread_cond_broadcast(&signal_2);
            } else {
                pthread_cond_broadcast(&signal_3);
            }
        }
    }
}

void *passenger(void *args) {
    int id = (intptr_t) args;
    int passangerStop = (rand() % 4 + 1);
    int exitPassengerStop = (rand() % 4 + 1);
    while (exitPassengerStop == passangerStop) {
        exitPassengerStop = (rand() % 4 + 1);
    }
    int isRiding = 0;
    busStopCounter[passangerStop - 1]++;
    printf("Passenger %d came to stop %d, exit stop: %d\n", id, passangerStop, exitPassengerStop);
    while (1) {
        //sleep(1);

        pthread_cond_wait(&signal_3, &busStation);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&bus); // passenger is boarding the bus

        if(isRiding == 1) {
            if(currentStop == exitPassengerStop) {
                printf("Passenger %d exited the bus at the stop %d\n", id, currentStop);
                isRiding = 0;
                bus_passenger_number--;
                passengersToGetOut[currentStop-1]-=1;
            }
        }
        if (isRiding == 1 && nextStop == exitPassengerStop) {
            passengersToGetOut[nextStop-1] = passengersToGetOut[nextStop-1] +=1;
            //printf("-------------WantsToGetOutAtNextStop: %d\n", id);
        }
        if (passangerStop == currentStop) {


            bus_passenger_number++;
            busStopCounter[passangerStop - 1]--;
            printf("Passenger %d boarded the bus\n", id);
            if(exitPassengerStop == nextStop) {
                passengersToGetOut[nextStop-1] = passengersToGetOut[nextStop-1]+=1;
                //printf("-------------WantsToGetOutAtNextStop: %d\n", id);
            }
            isRiding = 1;
            if (busStopCounter[passangerStop - 1] <= 0) { // no more passengers at stop, signal bus to depart
                pthread_cond_broadcast(&signal_2);
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&bus);
            }
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&bus); // passengers stop boarding the bus
    }
}

void *busDriving(void *args) {
    sleep(2);
    while (loop < 10) {

        printf("Bus arrived at stop %d\n", currentStop);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&bus);

        pthread_cond_broadcast(&signal_1); // signal that bus made it to the station
        pthread_cond_wait(&signal_2, &bus); // signal to board passengers

        printf("Current stop = %d\n", currentStop);
        printf("Bus passengers: %d\n", bus_passenger_number);
        sleep(5); //
        currentStop++;
        nextStop++;

        if (currentStop == 5) {
            currentStop = 1;
            loop++;
        }
        if (currentStop == 4) {
            nextStop = 1;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&bus);
    }

    printf("--------BUS WENT BACK TO DEPOT-------- LOOP: %d\n", loop);
}

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    pthread_t busDriver;
    pthread_t passengerID[PASSENGER_NUMBER];
    pthread_t busStopID[BUS_STOPS];

    pthread_mutex_init(&bus, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&busStation, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&passengerMutex, NULL);

    for (int i = 1; i < BUS_STOPS + 1; i++) {
        pthread_create(&busStopID[i], NULL, busStopp, (void *) (intptr_t) i);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < PASSENGER_NUMBER + 1; i++) {
        pthread_create(&passengerID[i], NULL, passenger, (void *) (intptr_t) i);
    }

    pthread_create(&busDriver, NULL, busDriving, NULL);

    for (int i = 1; i < BUS_STOPS + 1; i++) {
        pthread_join(busStopID[i], NULL);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < PASSENGER_NUMBER + 1; i++) {
        pthread_join(passengerID[i], NULL);
    }

    pthread_join(busDriver, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

I know the passenger function looks like a mess right now with that if conditions. I just tried so many things I ended up with it - stuck anyway...

My output right now is for example:

```
Passenger 1 came to stop 4, exit stop: 2
Passenger 2 came to stop 1, exit stop: 2
Passenger 3 came to stop 3, exit stop: 2
Passenger 4 came to stop 3, exit stop: 4
Passenger 5 came to stop 2, exit stop: 3
Passenger 6 came to stop 2, exit stop: 4
Passenger 7 came to stop 3, exit stop: 2
Passenger 8 came to stop 2, exit stop: 1
Passenger 9 came to stop 2, exit stop: 1
Passenger 10 came to stop 2, exit stop: 4
Bus arrived at stop 1
Passenger 2 boarded the bus
Current stop = 1
Bus passengers: 1
Bus arrived at stop 2
Passenger 6 boarded the bus
Passenger 8 boarded the bus
Passenger 10 boarded the bus
Passenger 9 boarded the bus
Passenger 5 boarded the bus
Current stop = 2
Bus passengers: 6
Bus arrived at stop 3
Passenger 7 boarded the bus
Passenger 4 boarded the bus
Passenger 5 exited the bus at the stop 3
Passenger 3 boarded the bus
...
```

Expected would be:

```
Passenger 1 came to stop 4, exit stop: 2
Passenger 2 came to stop 1, exit stop: 2
Passenger 3 came to stop 3, exit stop: 2
Passenger 4 came to stop 3, exit stop: 4
Passenger 5 came to stop 2, exit stop: 3
Passenger 6 came to stop 2, exit stop: 4
Passenger 7 came to stop 3, exit stop: 2
Passenger 8 came to stop 2, exit stop: 1
Passenger 9 came to stop 2, exit stop: 1
Passenger 10 came to stop 2, exit stop: 4
Bus arrived at stop 1
Passenger 2 boarded the bus
Current stop = 1
Bus passengers: 1
Bus arrived at stop 2
Passenger 2 exited the bus at the stop 2
Passenger 6 boarded the bus
Passenger 8 boarded the bus
Passenger 10 boarded the bus
Passenger 9 boarded the bus
Passenger 5 boarded the bus
Current stop = 2
Bus passengers: 5
Bus arrived at stop 3
Passenger 7 boarded the bus
Passenger 4 boarded the bus
Passenger 5 exited the bus at the stop 3
Passenger 3 boarded the bus
Current stop = 3
Bus passengers: 7
...
```

Comment: There's one thing that's very unclear: Which mutex protects which data? In addition to that, which condition variable is associated with which mutex? These are thing you should document clearly, using comments or perhaps grouping things in structures. With condition variables, you're also supposed to check a condition, I believe, because spontaneous wakeups happen. One mistake I also see is that it's not guaranteed that you call `pthread_cond_wait()` with a locked mutex, as you should. That said, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask], even though you're doing a great job!

Comment: So, really only mutex bus protects busDriving. 
signal_1 sends information from bus to busStop  that bus reached the stop. Then if there are people at the stop signal_3 sends information to passengers that they can board the bus. If there is no people on stop, signal_2 is being sent back to bus that it can proceed to drive to another station. Im not really protecting any data with busStation, only using it to send signal from busStop to passenger(I know that's probably not right thing to do). Rest of signals and mutex passengerMutex are not being used. I forgot to delete those.

Comment: signal_2 is also being sent after there were poeple at the station and everyone boarded the bus. The bus departure after receiving signal_2.

Comment: Maybe helpful to explain _why_ you are doing this. If I wanted a simulation of passengers riding a bus, then I would almost certainly do it all in a single thread. Probably, you are trying to learn something about how to use `pthread_cond_t` condition variables, but if so, then (A) see my "answer," below, and (B) maybe start out with something simpler like, a nice "producer/consumer" example in which just one "consumer" thread waits, and just one "producer" thread broadcasts the signal. Next step after that could be a multi-producer/multi-consumer demo.

Comment: "I forgot to delete those" -- [mcve]. Also, you can [edit] your question to clarify it, including providing more precise code.

Comment: @SolomonSlow besically yes, I'm trying to learn pthread_cond_t usage in multithreading. Your answer below is helpfull. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your program is complicated. It's so complicated that I am discouraged from trying to understand what it actually does. But, I can see at least one thing that you are doing wrong. There may be other problems that I haven't noticed, but let's look at how to use `pthread_cond_t` variables.

The important thing is that a waiting thread must never depend on a `pthread_cond_t` variable to tell it if some condition is true. The purpose of `pthread_cond_t` is to alert the thread that it should *check* whether or not the condition is true. There must be some other variable or some other means for the thread to test the condition, and there must be a mutex that *protects* the condition.

The reason why there must be some other variable is, a `pthread_cond_t` variable *does not remember* if it has been signalled. A `pthread_cond_broadcast` call will wake any thread that is sleeping on the condition *at that exact moment.* But if a thread calls `pthread_cond_wait` just *after* the broadcast, then it will wait until the *next* broadcast/signal. (Hopefully, there will *be* a next one. If not, then the waiting thread will wait forever.)

Here is a template for how to use `pthread_cond_t`. Pretty much any deviation from this template probably is a mistake.

**declarations**

```C
       #define TRUE  1
       #define FALSE 0
       #define boolean int

/*1*/  boolean         theCondition;
/*2*/  pthread_cond_t  theConditionVar;
/*3*/  pthread_mutex_t theMutex;
```

**pthread_cond_wait**

```C
/*3*/  pthread_mutex_lock(&theMutex);
       while (! theCondition) {
/*4*/      pthread_cond_wait(&theConditionVar, &theMutex);
       }
       doSomethingThatRequiresTheConditionToBeTrue(...);
/*5*/  theCondition = FALSE;
/*6*/  pthread_cond_broadcast(&theCondition);
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&theMutex);
```

**pthread_cond_broadcast**

```C
/*3*/  pthread_mutex_lock(&theMutex);
       ...
       theCondition = TRUE;
       pthread_cond_broadcast(&theCondition);
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&theMutex);
```

**/*1*/** The condition is explicitly testable. In this case, it's a simple boolean variable, but it could be any expression (e.g., a function call) that yields a TRUE/FALSE result.

**/*2*/** The condition variable can be used to notify waiting threads (if any) that `theCondition` has changed.

**/*3*/** Allows only one thread to use `theCondition` at the same time. No thread may ever change *or even look* at `theCondition` except when the thread has `theMutex` locked.

**/*4*/** The `pthread_cond_wait` call temporarily unlocks `theMutex` so that other threads can test or change `theCondition` while the caller is
sleeping. It guarantees to re-lock `theMutex` before it returns.

Also note: The while loop is not strictly necessary, but it is good hygiene to always use it. In some programs, there may be more than one "consumer" awaiting the same condition, and when a consumer wakes up, it re-tests to condition to see whether some *other* consumer already has dealt with it. Also, on some operating systems, it is possible for `pthread_cond_wait(...)` to "spuriously" return. I.E., it returns even though the condition was never signalled. Just get in the habit of always using a `while` loop, and you'll be safe.

**/*5*/** This is optional. Just because the thread was waiting for the condition to become TRUE does not necessarily mean that the thread is going to make it FALSE again. Only you (the programmer) know for sure.

**/*6*/** This also is optional. Just because the thread changed the condition to be FALSE does not necessarily mean that any other thread is *waiting* for it to become FALSE. Only you (the programmer) know for sure.